# How do I access current site handle in Craft 3 controllers

Tags: plugin-development, craft3

When my multisite is set up as @web/site, I cannot access the current site handle from my controllers.

```
Craft::$app->getSites()->currentSite->handle
```

I think this is because my form action defaults to the root site ie @web/actions/controller... rather than @web/site/actions/controller...

Is there a way to get the current site or do I need to pass it into the controller from the form?

Comment: Why doesn't `Craft::$app->getSites()->currentSite->handle` work? What is it returning for you?

Comment: It is returning the default site handle. I have a domain name example.com and multisites set up as example.com/site1 and example.com/site2. The controller gets called from example.com/actions/controller therefor retuning example as the site handle and not site1 or site2.

Comment: I'm having the same problem. Did you ever figure this out?

Answer (score 5):

I know this is a year and a half late, but maybe it helps someone else. I have a large multi-site project with a site for country and language. For example:

- Germany (German) - **default** - `/de-de/`
- Germany (English) - `/en-de/`
- Austria (German) - `/de-at/`
- Austria (English) - `/en-at/`
- etc

I was having this problem when posting to one of my controller's actions and then trying to get the `currentSite` within my plugin via `Craft::$app->getSites()->currentSite`.

In my JavaScript, my action looked like:

```
/actions/pluginHandle/controllerClass/actionMethod
```

Whenever I'd fetch the current site with `Craft::$app->getSites()->currentSite` it would always return the default site (Germany/German), and that's because I wasn't including the first URL segment (to get Austria/English, for example):

```
/en-at/actions/pluginHandle/controllerClass/actionMethod
```

Without that, Craft was resorting to getting the default site.

Answer (score 3):

With Craft CMS 3, you can spit out current site values directly with `currentSite`.

```
Site ID:            {{ currentSite.id }}
Site Handle:        {{ currentSite.handle }}
Site Name:          {{ currentSite.name }}
Site Language:      {{ currentSite.language }}
Is Primary Site?:   {{ currentSite.primary }}
Base URL:           {{ currentSite.baseUrl }}
```

https://docs.craftcms.com/v3/sites.html#site-groups

Comment: Question was about controllers; not twig.