# How to get current site (locale) api / plugin

Tags: plugin-development, localization, php

For my form plugin I'm using a global set of fields. These can be set in 2 languages `default` and `en`.

Problem is whenever I try to output them I cant dynamically make them use the current site locale/multi-site.

This is the current code:

```
$localeHandle = Craft::$app->getSites()->getCurrentSite()->handle;
    // form texts
    $entries = GlobalSet::find()
        ->siteId('*')
        ->site($localeHandle)
        ->handle('popupContact')
        ->asArray()
        ->one();
```

If `$localeHandle` is set to either `default` or `en` it works. I cant figure out how to get the handle though. Documentation doesn't state anything either.

Edit:
`Craft::$app->getSites()->getCurrentSite()->handle;` returns the default site handle.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know if this was the problem you were having but I was not including the site's first URL segment like `/en/` (in your example) with the controller action URL. So you'd want to post to `/en/actions/pluginHandle/controllerClass/actionMethod` to get the English site back when using `Craft::$app->getSites()->getCurrentSite()` in your plugin.

I posted a more thorough answer to the same problem in another ticket:
https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/a/33941/4433